# how to stop table duplicating (html, javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Me and my friend are making a chatbot in python and want it to send the unknown words to my website(using firebase), but when a word is added in real time, the table displays all of the previous words and the new word. Does anyone know how to fix it?
It is not that big of a problem because it condenses when you refresh the page.
[My website it is on](http://neotech.oyosite.com/neo_ai.html)

```js
var ref = new Firebase("https://chatbot-errors.firebaseio.com/Errors");
ref.on("value", setTable , function (errorObject) {
 console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

function setTable(data){
    var i = 0;
    var table = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(table);
 console.log(table);
    var newTable1 = '<tr><td>one</td>';
    var newtable2 = '<td>two</td>';
    var newtable3 = '<td id="data1">three</td>';
    var newTable4 = '<td id=>four</td> <td></td></tr>';
    for (i; i < keys.length; i++){
        console.log(i);
        var k = keys[i]
  
        var dates = table[k].date;
        
        var time = table[k].time;
        
        var names = table[k].name;

        var wordsAre = table[k].word;

        console.log(names, wordsAre);
        
        var good1 = newTable1.replace('one', dates); 
        var good2 = newtable2.replace('two', time); 
        var good3 = newtable3.replace('three', names); 
        var good4 = newTable4.replace('four', wordsAre);;
        var good5 = good1+good2+good3+good4;
        
        document.getElementById("tabless").innerHTML += good5;
    }
}
```

```css
/*
 * Base structure
 */

/* Move down content because we have a fixed navbar that is 50px tall */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}


/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Top navigation
 * Hide default border to remove 1px line.
 */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 51px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

 <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
 <script src="neo_ai.js"></script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="neotech.png">

    <title>Stats</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Words <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Chat Logs</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <main class="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">

          
          <h2>Unimplemented Words</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Time</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Word</th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody id="tabless">
                <!---<tr>
                  <td id="date">----</td>
                  <td id="time">----</td>
                  <td id="data1">----</td> 
                  <td id="wor">----</td> 
                  <td></td>
                </tr>--->
                
                
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are appending new html: `innerHTML += good5`. Clear the element, or remove the previous table element before adding the new table

Comment: @Andy Levine, use `jquery Template` , it is easy for your solution. look this link: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks for the help i will try it out

Comment: @chiragsatapara thanks for the help i will try it out